# Parametric JpaRepository (or "subrepository")

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

here is generic problem: I want to get a JpaRepository instance somehow, which will serve not all data from a table but a custom filtered set of a data. In another words, the same effect may be achieved if I would be able somehow to append a custom AND-condition to every Query Method of a specific JpaRepository.

Let's look to an example, hope it helps understanding my question:

Mind DB with Book and User tables. Every Book entity has some properties like title, description, pageCount, author and **owner** which is @ManyToOne (an Owner have many Books). I.e the Book table data is logically splitted to large groups by an owner. In my code I create interface `BookRepository` with query methods like `findByName(String), findByAuthor(String)`, but I want to always distinguish returned books by some User (owner) I'm serving at the moment. Then I need to modify my methods to `findByNameAndOwner(String,User), findByAuthorAndOwner(String,User)` and so on. This is ugly and it feels like I'm missing some nice Spring Data or JPA feature.

Is there some way to have some repository factory like:

```
User someOwner = ...;
BookRepository repo = BookByOwnerRepositoryFactory.getRepositoryFor(someOwner);
```

where `BookRepository` is still like this:

```
interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book,Long>
{
  List<Book> findByName(String name);
  List<Book> findByAuthor(String author);
  ...
}
```

used:

```
List<Book> javaBooks = repo.findByName("Effective Java");
```

but `javaBooks` will contain books owned by `someOwner` only, and effectively be result of such query:

`select b from Book b where b.name='Effective Java' and b.owner_id=42`

where 42 is `someOwner.id`. As you can see, the last part `and b.owner_id=42` should be internally appended to an every query generated for query methods of `BookRepository`.

Comment: I think this approach goes agains the way Spring Data JPA is meant to be used. You are hiding half of the information from someone who might look at the code and this is not good. More importantly, this would mean you create a new instance everytime the service gets invoked, adding lots of unnecessary overhead when you can just keep them as singletons.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Querydsl or specifications like [here](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl)

In repository you will have method findAll which as parameter have conditions.